# Copying a file hash to clipboard without PowerShell

Tags: windows, batch

… isn't easy.

```
@echo off&(for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('certutil -hashfile "%1" MD5') do echo %%a&for /f "delims=" %%b in ('echo %%a^|findstr /r /i /x [0-9A-F]*') do if "%%b" neq "" echo %%b|clip&pause&exit)&pause
```

PowerShell is slow to load so I used batch instead. I use this command to extend the context menu of windows explorer, hence a single line.

There is one minor issue; `certutil` doesn't support empty files.

Bonus registry entries: https://paste.ee/p/sgSJY

Comment: Why not put in multiple lines? Programs associated with file types can be arbitrarily long, as long as the invocation is single line.

Answer (score 2):

All zero-sized files will have the same checksum using the same given hash algorithm. Hence, use the following batch-script:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
for /f %%G in ("%~1") do set "_len=%%~zG"
if %_len% EQU 0 (
  echo MD5 hash of %1
  echo D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E
  echo CertUtil bypassed for zero file size
  echo D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E|clip  
) else (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('certutil -hashfile "%~1" MD5') do (
    echo %%a
    for /f "delims=" %%b in ('echo %%a^|findstr /r /i /x ^[0-9A-F]*[0-9A-F]$') do (
      if "%%b" neq "" echo %%b|clip
    )
  )
)
pause
```

Note that *`%%~zG` expands `%%G` to size of file* (read `call /?`).

`if "%%b" neq "" echo %%b|clip` seems to be superfluous then. Simple `echo %%b|clip` should suffice.

Sample output:

```
==> D:\bat\CodeReview\179105.bat out.txt
MD5 hash of out.txt
D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E
CertUtil bypassed for zero file size
Press any key to continue . . .

==> D:\bat\CodeReview\179105.bat D:\bat\CodeReview\179105.bat
MD5 hash of D:\bat\CodeReview\179105.bat:
c2a4cabffac79a26ee5ed7c97cefb44b
CertUtil: -hashfile command completed successfully.
Press any key to continue . . .

==>
```